# What are other ways than "Natural" to define trees ?

Tags: data-structures, tree

I am reading [Data Structure and Algorithm Analysis in Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132576279) Chapter 4 - Trees. 
I am quoting:

> A tree can be defined in several ways. One natural way to define a
>   tree is recursively

What are ***other ways*** to define trees, other than ***natural way*** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a tree using the terminology of graph theory:

*A tree is a connected, acyclic, undirected graph.*

Or you could describe it by the elements of which it consists:

*A tree is a (possibly non-linear) data structure made up of nodes or vertices and edges without having any cycle. The tree with no nodes is called the null or empty tree.* (Wikipedia)

Your quote refers to the fact that for a node of a tree all of its children are individual trees, hence the simple (recursive) definition.

Answer (score 1):

Here *several ways* contrasts against *recursion*, not *natural* - meaning that there are other ways than recursion to generate a tree instance. You could use loops, for example. Recursion is *natural* because it's an obvious and elegant strategy for this task, as every subtree is itself a tree. Here, recursive code will be much cleaner and easier to understand (assuming you understand recursion) than a loop implementation.